# codeigniter php native sessions without using cookies or URL session id, but matching browserfingerprints in database

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, native, session-cookies, overwrite

Because of european privacy law being harsly applied in the Netherlands and to keep my company's site user friendly without nagging the users with questions if it's okay to store a cookie on their computer that allows me to access their client data.

What I need is a way to "overwrite" the native php sessions class so that at the point where the native class requests the cookie that stores the phpsessid, that I can place my own code there that checks the browsers fingerprint and matches that to a session id which I can use to return the normal working of the native class.

My idea is:

table sess_fingerprints
Fields: fingerprint - phpsessid

```
function getsessionid()
    {
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT phpsessid 
                    FROM `sessiondatabase`.`sess_fingerprints` 
                    WHERE `sess_fingerprints`.`fingerprint` = '$userfingerprint'");
    if($result->num_rows() != 0)
        {
        return $result->row->phpsessid;
        }
    }
```

and at that point the native php session code just works as it would normally do.

So, my question is: is it possible to overwrite only the "cookie" part of the phpsession class? if so, how? because I haven't found that yet.

I'm aware of being able to pass along the session variable via urls etc, but that's not secure enough for my web applications.

Comment: this maybe of some help - https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1375

Comment: I've joined that discussion. Thank you for that link, but I also need this for orther sites that don't use code igniter.

What I need is just a way to kill the cookie part of the native session class and replace it with my own. That way It doens't matter if I have codeigniter, joomla, concrete or some other obscure software package. Then I only need to add my own line's at the beginning and that way I can ensure it working compliant with the law.
My fingerprinting software works as espected. Now to replace the session cookie setting functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution to my problem.
I'm going to override the functions related to cookies by using http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Thank you all for thinking along.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides support for custom session handlers:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php

Comment: I've read through it that manual, but what I want is to replace only the cookie retrieving part. Not all the other code. Is there a way to replace only one specific part?
I'm using php 5.3, so I can't use a parent::do your thing construction to have the original code do it's thing.

Comment: The example here [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) provides a session handler similar to the PHP one, I'd consider just using that.

Comment: I have read through it, but this all does not handle the cookie part.
I want to use my own fingerprinting software to give the native class the session id.
I do not need to rewrite the enitire session read/write mechanism.
I only need to intercept the code where the cookie is written/sessionid is appended to the URL.
That part of the code I wish to replace, and that part does not get replaced by the session handler code examples you posted.